# Tweepy Error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tweepy

im trying to make a tweepy bot and i keep getting this error and i have no idea what to do about it

```
File "main.py, line 9, in <module>
 for tweet in tweets.data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

im using python 3.6.9 and tweepy 4.4.0

my code is below

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='mybearertoken')

query = 'from:user -is:reply'

tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query)

for tweet in tweets.data:
  print(tweet.text)
```

if anybody could help i would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is no data in tweets. This could result from either there being no recent tweets from wherever you got them from or you are not polling the data correctly. Check over [tweepys docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?highlight=search%20recent#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets) to make sure you are correctly getting the data, and if you are and None is an expected return, you should always check before you iterate over the data if it `is None` or not. This should fix the error you are currently having.